# Update a remote database using C# and a DataSet

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

I have a remote Oracle database and a certain table that I am interested in. For my C# program, I created a DataSet using VS DataSet designer, and added a `TableAdapter` for that table.

Now I need to add a new row to that database table. At first, I tried to add insert a row query in my dataset adapter like this:

[image]

And then, in order to access it, I used this code:

```
DataSetTableAdapters.INVENTURTableAdapter inventur_adapter = new INVENTURTableAdapter();

inventur_adapter.InsertQuery( arg1, arg2, arg3, ...);
```

which didn't throw any errors, but it didn't update the remote database either.

After this I tried a method listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/edit-data-in-datasets?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp):

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 DataSet.INVENTURRow newInventurRow = ds.INVENTUR.NewINVENTURRow();

 newInventurRow.SOMEARG = value;
 ...
 ds.NIESSING.Rows.Add(newInventurRow);
```

which also didn't throw any errors, and also did not update the remote database.

I guess in both examples it is because I need to create a new instance of that dataset, yet I cannot understand how can "merge" newly created instance of dataset with that remote table

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/insert-new-records-into-a-database?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) They use this line to save changes:

```
this.regionTableAdapter.Update(this.northwindDataSet.Region);
```

so with my example it should be:

```
DataSetTableAdapters.INVENTURTableAdapter.Update(DataSet.INVENTUR);
```

The problem is that I can't use "DataSet.INVENTUR". I can only use `INVENTURDataTable`, which does not work

or I can do it this way:

```
DataSetTableAdapters.INVENTURTableAdapter.Update(ds.INVENTUR);
```

Which will throw an error:

> An object reference is required for non-static

How can I actually save the updated data?

Comment: Hi, When accessing a non-static member of a class without an instance of the class, the error message "non-static requires an object reference" usually occurs. At this time, it should be necessary to create an instance of the INVENTURTableAdapter class before calling the Update method. One more thing I don't quite understand is why you can't use DataSet.INVENTUR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way how I managed to solve this:

```
 DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
 DataSetTableAdapters.INVENTURTableAdapter adapter = new DataSetTableAdapters.INVENTURTableAdapter();
 DataSet.INVENTURGRow newInventurRow = dataSet.INVENTUR.NewINVENTURGRow();
            
            newInventurRow.<COLUMNNAME1> = <VALUE1>
            ...
            newInventurRow.<COLUMNNAME99> = <VALUE99>

adapter.Update(dataSet.INVENTUR);
```

Maybe not the optimal way to do this, but it is the only way I managed to solve it and it works.